# ViewPort method without zoom effect in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, zooming, viewport, effect

I'm trying to Slice an image to show on a screen.
For example if I change the right margin to 20 of the flower picture on the left and the bottom margin of the flower picture in the right to 20 they should behave as follow:

(the original pictures are shown in the first column)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVaua.png)

ViewPort method does exactly what I want, cutting the image and leaving the margin empty but it uses image's original size displaying a zoom effect as it says in the javafx website:

"The rectangular viewport into the image. The viewport is specified in the coordinates of the image, prior to scaling or any other transformations.
If viewport is null, the entire image is displayed. If viewport is non-null, only the portion of the image which falls within the viewport will be displayed. If the image does not fully cover the viewport then any remaining area of the viewport will be empty."

I already tried to use `imageView.resize(screenWidth, screenHeight)` before setting the viewport but it doesn't work.
Also tried to `imageView.setFitWidth(screenWidth), imageView.setFitHeight(screenHeight)`
Is it possible to rescale the image so it's displayed as described?
Or any other work-around?

Here is my code for left margin as an example:
`mediaContent.resize(screenWidth, screen.getHeight());
//  mediaContent.setFitWidth(screenWidth);
//  mediaContent.setFitHeight(screen.getHeight());
 mediaContent.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(screenWidth-dXLeft, 0, screenWidth, screen.getHeight()));`

**Update**: Tried setting `setFitWidth` and `setFitHeight`as suggested stills displays the image zoomed in

```
    `imageView.setFitWidth(space.getX());
    imageView.setFitHeight(space.getY());
    imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(screen.getWidth()-space.getX(), 0, screen.getWidth(), screen.getHeight()));
    imageView.setFitWidth(space.getX());
    imageView.setFitHeight(space.getY());

    return imageView;`
```

This is the result when I use the `setViewport` method when not 
setting margins: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe6ow.png)

How it should be when not setting margins: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB0Ev.png)

**Update 2**: Example (modified from java-buddy) zooming in

```
package javafx_imageview_viewport;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @web http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/
 */
public class JavaFX_ImageView_Viewport extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(new Image("https://i.imgur.com/6Zl0eQB.jpg"));
    imageView1.setFitWidth(150);
    imageView1.setFitHeight(100);

    //Example to rotate ImageView
    Image image2 = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/6Zl0eQB.jpg");
    Rectangle2D viewportRect2 = new Rectangle2D(
            image2.getWidth()/4, 
            image2.getHeight()/4, 
            image2.getWidth()*3/4, 
            image2.getHeight()*3/4);
    ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image2);
    imageView2.setFitWidth(150);
    imageView2.setFitHeight(100);
    imageView2.setViewport(viewportRect2);

    Slider sliderRotate = new Slider();
    sliderRotate.setMin(0);
    sliderRotate.setMax(360);
    sliderRotate.setValue(0);
    sliderRotate.valueProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, 
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        imageView2.setRotate((double)newValue);
    });

    //Example to change ViewPort
    Image image3 = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/6Zl0eQB.jpg");
    Rectangle2D viewportRect3 = new Rectangle2D(
            0, 
            0, 
            image3.getWidth(), 
            image3.getHeight());
    ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(image3);
    imageView3.setFitWidth(150);
    imageView3.setFitHeight(100);
    imageView3.setViewport(viewportRect3);

    Slider sliderViewPort = new Slider();
    sliderViewPort.setMin(0);
    sliderViewPort.setMax(1.0);
    sliderViewPort.setValue(1.0);
    sliderViewPort.valueProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, 
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        Rectangle2D newViewportRect3 = new Rectangle2D(
                0,
                0,
                (double)newValue*image3.getWidth(),
                (double)newValue*image3.getHeight());
        imageView3.setViewport(newViewportRect3);
    });


    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(imageView1, 
            imageView2, sliderRotate,
            imageView3, sliderViewPort);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(vBox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 350);

    primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy: ImageVIew ViewPort");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}    
}
```

Example 2 from java-buddy how I want it to behave, cutting the image:

```
package javafx_imageview_viewport;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @web http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/
 */
public class JavaFX_ImageView_Viewport extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView(new Image("https://i.imgur.com/294AEFU.png"));

    //Example to rotate ImageView
    Image image2 = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/294AEFU.png");
    Rectangle2D viewportRect2 = new Rectangle2D(
            image2.getWidth()/4, 
            image2.getHeight()/4, 
            image2.getWidth()*3/4, 
            image2.getHeight()*3/4);
    ImageView imageView2 = new ImageView(image2);
    imageView2.setViewport(viewportRect2);

    Slider sliderRotate = new Slider();
    sliderRotate.setMin(0);
    sliderRotate.setMax(360);
    sliderRotate.setValue(0);
    sliderRotate.valueProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, 
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        imageView2.setRotate((double)newValue);
    });

    //Example to change ViewPort
    Image image3 = new Image("https://i.imgur.com/294AEFU.png");
    Rectangle2D viewportRect3 = new Rectangle2D(
            0, 
            0, 
            image3.getWidth(), 
            image3.getHeight());
    ImageView imageView3 = new ImageView(image3);
    imageView3.setViewport(viewportRect3);

    Slider sliderViewPort = new Slider();
    sliderViewPort.setMin(0);
    sliderViewPort.setMax(1.0);
    sliderViewPort.setValue(1.0);
    sliderViewPort.valueProperty().addListener(
            (ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, 
                    Number oldValue, Number newValue) -> {
        Rectangle2D newViewportRect3 = new Rectangle2D(
                0,
                0,
                (double)newValue*image3.getWidth(),
                (double)newValue*image3.getHeight());
        imageView3.setViewport(newViewportRect3);
    });


    VBox vBox = new VBox();
    vBox.getChildren().addAll(imageView1, 
            imageView2, sliderRotate,
            imageView3, sliderViewPort);

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(vBox);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 350);

    primaryStage.setTitle("java-buddy: ImageVIew ViewPort");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: You should call `setFitWidth` and `setFitHeight` with the dimensions of the portion of the image you want to display (not the dimensions of the screen).

Comment: Before or after calling the `setViewport` method?

Comment: I don't think it matters.

Comment: It still shows the image zoomed in

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. No-one but you knows what values you are passing to these methods.

Comment: Ok, I will provide it.

Comment: @James_D Posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what I wanted does not make sense.

If I want the image to fit the screen I have to use `fitScreenWidth(screenWidth)`and `fitScreenHeight(screenHeight)` but it does not make sense to use `viewPort` method in this case since the image has been resized already.

viewPort method should be used only with the original image's dimensions.